# Как перенести старый проект с ANT на Gradle?

Tags: java, android

Переношу старый проект с ANT на Gradle. Проект использует старые библиотеки. и я никак не могу найти их или альтернативу им.  конкретно интересно что это за ерунда

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

и в другом классе

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
```

еще

```
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Как мне найти эти библиотеки? в старом проекте они в самом SDK как я понял лежал. Или на что поменять, чтобы не переписывать много кода?

Answer (score 1):

В работе Android произошли изменения, [почитайте тут](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

> В M Preview удалена поддержка HTTP-клиента Apache. Если ваше приложение, разработанное для Android 2.3 (уровень API 9) или более поздней версии, использует этот клиент, вам необходимо воспользоваться вместо него классом HttpURLConnection. Этот API-интерфейс более эффективный, поскольку он сокращает использование сетевого трафика за счет прозрачного сжатия и кэширования ответов, а также сводит к минимуму потребление энергии. Чтобы продолжить использовать API-интерфейсы HTTP Apache, сначала объявите в своем файле build.gradle следующую зависимость compile-time:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/)

Декларировать в Gradle так:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2+'
```

Comment: в том то и суть что в последнем нету этих классов